# How To drag and drop files/images out of Plone site to Linux desktop

Tags: plone

I wish to drag and  drop files/images **out of Plone site** to Linux desktop. Is such a feature available with any Plone products? I am using Plone 4.1

Answer (score 1):

you've to install enfold desktop, both server and client. Or relay on webdav native support in plone:

http://www.enfoldsystems.com/

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/webdav

Comment: OP asked about "Linux desktop" -- WebDAV is spot-on, but Enfold Desktop is Windows-only.

Comment: server component of enfold help webdav to work better on Linux too :-) but I agree the client is only for Windows, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your favorite WebDAV client for your desktop environment (e.g. if you use Gnome, use GVFS support for WebDAV) -- or consider using FUSE.  Plone supports DAV out of the box -- and for files, this does not require running Zope using a special webdav TCP port, you just use the normal site URL.  Note: YMMV with various proxies in between your desktop and Plone/Zope (e.g. nginx does not support chunked HTTP PUT requests, which trips up DAV in Mac OS X Finder, so you never know what interop issues to expect without testing your client/server combo).

Answer (score 0):

I use: http://plone.org/products/collective.quickupload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1310105/jhb with http://plone.org/products/collective.quickupload, we can drag & drop files/images from desktop into the Plone site, "not out of it"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pure HTML5/Javascript solution might be possible in Chrome at least: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/box_dnd_download/